# Can get the vlaue from string

Tags: asp.net

So I am trying to make the user input information that displays after clicking a button. I get the message but it doenst show the value input into the textbox. What am I missing?
here is my code

```
private string _eyecolor;
    public string Eyecolor
    {
        get { return _eyecolor; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _eyecolor = value.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + value.Substring(1);
            }
            else
            {
                _eyecolor = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string getEyeColor()
    {
        return "You have " + _eyecolor + "eyes!!";
    }
```

Here is my html code:

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_1" AssociatedControlID="txtb1" Text="what is your eyes color?" Autopostback="true" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtb1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="subSubmit" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_output" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my codebehind:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   Profile P = new Profile();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
protected void  subSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lbl_output.Text=P.getMsg();
   lbl_output.Text+=P.getEyeColor();
}
}
```

Comment: At the moment you're missing any kind of code that injects anything into a textbox.

Comment: We need to see your code behind (the entire thing, as well as the code in front if this is webforms (the `.aspx`, and the `aspx.cs`.

Comment: I have posted everything now. Please see what I am missing.

Comment: Post code for this - `P.getMsg();` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adil quite rightly pointed out, you need to grab the value from the `<asp:TextBox>` input and assign it to your property `Eyecolor`.

Since `getEyeColor` is a function of the `Profile` object `P` in your posted code, try changing your Submit handler to the following:

```
protected void subSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    P.Eyecolor = txtb1.Text.Trim; //Add this to set the Eyecolor to user input.
    lbl_output.Text = P.getMsg();
    lbl_output.Text += P.getEyeColor();
}
```

Comment: It worked after I used the line that you suggested, but I used ToString() instead of trim .

Comment: `.Text` is already of type `String`, so you're effectively calling `String.ToString()` which (while not harmful) is redundant. I put the trim on there so you wouldn't end up with eye colors like `'    green     '`

Answer (score 1):

You need some input control and you have assign its value to some gui control to get it displayed.

**In html**

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtInput" runat="server" Text="Blue" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<asp:Label id="lbl" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

**In Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Eyecolor = "Blue";
    lbl.Text = getEyeColor();
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      lbl.Text = txtInput.Text;
}
```

**As update in question.**

You are having input from user but not using it in the output. `You need to show txtb1 text in lbl_1 Text`. Which could be done by the statement

lbl.Text = txtInput.Text;

You are using Profile class object and you did not assign color to Profile class object property `if you do not want txtb1 color then you have to assign color to profile object before assigning to lbl_1  text` which does not make much sense but for understanding you need something like.

```
protected void  subSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //lbl_output.Text=P.getMsg();
   P.Eyecolor = "Blue";
   lbl_output.Text+=P.getEyeColor();
}
```

Comment: I already have html file and code behind file. I only posted the class file. the messae displayed onClick is supposed to contain the eyecolor.

Comment: I have updated my answer with little more explanation. Please read it carefully and tell me if you have any queries.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. I wanted to have the user input to be used in the msg.